# Data allocation

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Im working on a program to time memory allocation using Calloc() with some timing, 
the program should try and allocate 50megs and iterate with 50 more megs every time,
until it allocated 1500 megs of ram. The objective of createbigthing() is just to create something big and freeing it.

```
....
#define oneMeg 1024L*1024L
#define INCREMENT 50

int difftod(struct timeval * tv0, struct timeval * tv1){
return (tv1->tv_sec - tv0->tv_sec)*1000 + (tv1->tv_usec- tv0->tv_usec)/1000;
}


int createbigthing(long int size){

int *test = (int*) calloc(size, (size_t) oneMeg);
if(test == NULL){
    return -1;
}

free(test);
return 0;
}


int main(){
long int i;
int rtn;
struct timeval tv0, tv1;
struct timezone tzp;
for(i=INCREMENT;i<=1500;i=i+INCREMENT){
        rtn = gettimeofday(&tv0, &tzp); /* set timer T0 */
        createbigthing(i);
    rtn = gettimeofday(&tv1, &tzp); /* read time T1 */
    printf("%d msec\n",difftod(&tv0,&tv1));
}
return 0;
}
```

The only output i get is that the first iteration is giving me about 220 msec of delay and then nothing, the function is still returning 0 so the memory shouldnt be full.

Output example:

```
220 msec
0 msec
0 msec
0 msec
0 msec
...
```

Comment: Try writing at least one byte into each page. New pages are zero by default and COW, so with any luck your current program is doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely expected behaviour:

- You are requesting one Mebibyte from the system kernel once (inside `calloc()`), this takes time (it shouldn't be 220 msec, though).
- You free this memory, telling the libc (not the kernel) that you don't need it anymore. The libc won't return the memory to the system in most cases, so it's still part of your virtual address space.
- You tell the libc again, that you need one Mebibyte of RAM, and the libc says: Oh, great, I still got one big suitable block here. Take it! It will also erase its contents, because you use `calloc()`, but that won't take time in the millisecond range.

Also note, that your time differencing code will round down any time difference below one millisecond. You might want to change it to print elapsed microseconds.